# Handling of Multiple Boost installs is broken in ROS Fuerte

Tags: boost, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the latest ROS Fuerte from aptitude on Ubuntu 10.4.  I have 2 boost installs.  A 1.40.0 install in /usr/include and a 1.50.0 install in /usr/local/include.  rosboost-cfg is aware of both installations.  CMake functionality in this regards is broken however:

---

When compiling a "main" program, CMake will correctly identify both installations and will state that it is using the latest.  After compiling a "main" program, I get the following linking errors:

CMakeFiles/pc_transformer.dir/src/pc_transformer.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0': /usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to` boost::system::generic_category()'
/usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:215: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()' /usr/local/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp:216: undefined reference to` boost::system::system_category()'

This is a results of CMake using the /usr/local *include* files and the /usr *shared objects*.  This can be verified because linkage works if the following line is placed in the CMake file

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_LD_FLAGS} -L/usr/local/lib")

---

If I set ROS_BOOST_VERSION=1.40.0 before compiling I still get the same error referencing the include files from 1.50.0.  Clearly CMake is not obeying ROS_BOOST_VERSION properly.  Additionally, it is inconsistent in the boost root directory it chooses for include files and shared objects

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42285/handling-of-multiple-boost-installs-is-broken-in-ros-fuerte/) by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2012-08-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a bug. Please [open a defect ticket](https://github.com/ros/ros) to report it, prefixing the issue name with `rosboost_cfg:`.

You can provide a link back to this question to avoid repeating the details.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-08-27**:
This should be opened against `rosboost_cfg` which is in the `ros` repository:
https://github.com/ros/ros

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-28**:
Thanks, William. Edited the link in the answer above.